# I am trying to edit the Django database but this error keeps happening:The view social.views.edit didn't return an HttpResponse object

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

This is my code for my view:

def edit(request):

```
if request.method == 'POST':

    form = EditProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)

else:

    if form.is_valid():

        user = form.save()

    form = EditProfileForm(instance=request.user)

    args = {'form': form}

    return render(request, 'social/edit.html', args)
```

And here is the code for the form:

class EditProfileForm(UserChangeForm):

```
edit ='social/edit.html'

class Meta:

    model = UserProfile

    fields = ('description', 'image')
```

Here is the model:

class UserProfile(models.Model):

```
description = models.CharField(max_length=300, default=' ', blank=True)

image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_image', blank=True)
```

if you need any more information to help I would be more than gladly to give it to you

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the view function.

Every View must return some sort of response (HTTP Response in General)

you have an if else statement in your view if its a post it will just execute

```
form = EditProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
```

and then it doesn't return anything.

I think you have to do is,

For GET Request (when you visit the url, it has to render the form)

```
if request.method == 'GET':
    form = EditProfileForm(instance=request.user)
    args = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'social/edit.html', args)
```

For POST request (when you send POST to this view or different one)

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = EditProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)

    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.save()

    # use render/redirect as needed. make sure it returns an HTTP Response
    # note that render method also return HTTP Response
    return HttpResponse('Done')
```

Make sure Form class is simply this

```
class EditProfileForm(UserChangeForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('description', 'image')
```

Comment: I just tried it and it only said done and nothing actually changed. No media file was stored or description in the database.

Comment: Try Changing UserChangeForm into from django.forms import ModelForms

Comment: Also Try, print(form.is_valid()) print(form.errors) print(form.cleaned_data) after form.is_valid() and before return. These would help you see values in console